# How can I detect accessibility gestures from within a custom view?

Tags: android, custom-controls, accessibility, gesture

I need to make a custom view detect and react to Jellybean's accessibility gestures (eg: scroll a page, swipe focus). An example would be appreciated. I can't seem to find anything definitive in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to intercept some AccessibilityEvents by writing a custom AccessibilityDelegate (call View.setAccessibilityDelegate()): http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.AccessibilityDelegate.html

Unfortunately I have not been able to find a way to intercept the swipe focus event that tabs between view elements. I think you may be able to do so by writing an AccessibilityService and then having it pass information back to your app, but it seems like Accessibility Services are designed to be used with multiple apps, and they have to be manually enabled in accessibility options by the user, AND the order in which they receive events depends on the order in which they were enabled.